# Parsing JSON object in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to make some (JSON) API calls to our Wi-Fi controller and obtain some info. When I store the JSON response into a `dict` somehow it only see's a few keys, namely:

```
   dict_keys(['totalCount', 'hasMore', 'firstIndex', 'list'])
```

and items:

```
   dict_items([('totalCount', 32), ('hasMore', False), ('firstIndex', 0), 
   ('list', [{'id': 'ehgfhafgf', 'name': 'fasdfsd 
   xxxx'}, {'id': 'efasfsfas', 
   'name': 'zxcva'}])])
```

I removed a lot of items so It would make some sense otherwise it would be too much text.

So as you can see the `dict` recognizes the wrong variables as keys. Because as keys I need `id` and `name`. Is there a way to manually assign `dict` keys or a trick to simulate this?

My piece of code:

```
#Method that retrieves all zones
def getZones():
    r = requests.get("url..", verify=False, cookies=cookie)
    print(type(r.json()))
    jsonResponse = r.json()
    print("items: \n") 
    print(jsonResponse.items())
    print("\nkeys: \n")
    print(jsonResponse.keys())
    print(jsonResponse.get('id'))
    return r
```

doing a lot of prints for debugging reasons.

Comment: just to be thorough what is the json exactly-the complete dictionary {key: value, etc}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question would have been clearer if you had shown the actual JSON response.

However, it is clear from what you have posted that `id` and `name` are indeed not top-level keys, but keys inside nested dictionaries inside a list assigned to the `list` key. So you should get them from there:

```
for item in jsonResponse['list']:
    print(item['id'], item['name'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I will try it immediately. I wasn't able to post it completely since there is confidential data in the response